# How to COPY / ADD resources via a Dockerfile for privileged users?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

What's the best way to build a custom container from a Dockerfile with custom configuration files? I want to do something like this:

```
FROM jboss/wildfly:latest
USER jboss
COPY configuration/standalone.xml /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/
```

But as a result the copied resource is owned by user 'root'. This is how the Docker documentation explains the COPY and ADD command. The USER switch is ignored.

So my question is: should I always run a chown command after copy/add new resources?

```
FROM jboss/wildfly:latest
USER jboss
COPY configuration/standalone.xml /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/
RUN chown -R jboss /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/
```

This looks a little bit clumsy to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> That looks a little clumsy to me?

Yes, it is clumsy, and it was discussed in [issue 7537](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7537), even patched in [PR 9934](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/9934).
But rejected.

You can look into [PR 10775](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/10775) and its `COPY --user=` option, which was merged.